# Focus type css while hovering on html button in IE

Tags: html, css, focus

On a page when we tab across elements, they get focused and those elements get highlighted with some browser specific css.

Like on button when focused it shows like below screen shot.

> Notice the white dotted line on button

[image]

I would like to show exactly similar when button is `hovered`

```
button:hover {
   /*What should go here?*/
}
```

Comment: used to button:focus{outline:none;}, outline:0;

Comment: @RohitAzad I would like to show the outline and that too on hover with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Screetop/tpx5tyxc/
As mentioned by the others, take a look at the outline property. Also the box-shadow simulates a border around your button.

```
<button>Submit</button>

button {
    display: block;
    background: grey;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px grey;
}
button:hover {
   /*What should go here?*/
    outline: 1px dotted white;
}
button:focus {
    outline: 1px dotted white;
}
```

Comment: Yes I need exactly same as you have shown in js fiddle. Will this work in IE8?

Comment: You would probably want to swap the order of `:hover` and `:focus`. I think accessibility wise the best order is `:link` `:visited` `:focus` `:hover` `:active`. This gives you the best way of overriding the styles

Comment: I believe outline will work, box-shadow however not. I believe there is a workaround: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/. @Adam thanks for the tip :) But why this particular order? @ Ahs nice work :)

Comment: Its this order so that a visited link will always override a standard link. But a hovered, focused or active link will override a visited link. Same as active will then override a hover link (active is a bit like a button down event). 
This link has more info http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html

Answer (score 0):

There’s the CSS [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property, but it won’t render inside the element. If we use a simple `border` for the dotted line, we nee to get some spacing between the dots and the visible border. Perhaps using [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)? Try this:

```
button{
    width:140px;
    height:36px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#555;
    border:1px dotted #555;
    border-radius:2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #555;
}
button:hover{
    border-color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Instead of removing I want to keep the outline when button is hovered. I do not want to remove it.